# Why is my sample application Elastic Beanstalk + Node.js keep failing?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used to manually create EC2 instances and everything necessary along with it -- SG, ALB, TG, S3 for bundle and even CI/CD with CodeCommit and endless journey with it, which I did find burdensome.

Then I figured Elastic Beanstalk is supposed to do all of the process for me.

It even came with the sample application zip file, on which I could build my application on. Perfect. Awesome.

But whenever I hit that choose file and upload, everything falls apart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awX9a.png)

All I did was to add just three lines to the sample application's package.json

```
{
  "name": "Elastic-Beanstalk-Sample-App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pm2": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm i && node app.js"
  }
}
```

The log also shows following:

```
2022/12/16 07:07:42.222994 [INFO] installing specified nodejs version...
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223002 [INFO] there is no package.json file, skip installing specified version of nodejs
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223009 [INFO] Executing instruction: Use NPM to install dependencies
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223019 [INFO] there is no package.json file, skip installing dependencies
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223023 [INFO] Executing instruction: check Procfile
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223027 [INFO] checking Procfile
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223033 [INFO] no Procfile found, generating Procfile
2022/12/16 07:07:42.223036 [INFO] checking package.json file
```

All I ever wanted was to deploy simple express.js server with simple endpoints.

Will I ever escape that green default Congratulations page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out I'm not supposed to zip the source folder from the top level.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).